# file_get_contents(includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' )) not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the contents from the local jQuery path in my WordPress theme. I am doing the following code:

`$jq = file_get_contents(includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ));`

when I echo out the variable `jq` there is nothing stored in it

`echo $mergedJs; // nothing`

This only happens when I upload the theme to the server - it works fine on my local machine, which is odd. How can I fix it?

Comment: try adding `__DIR__` like this: `$jq = file_get_contents(includes_url( __DIR__ .'/js/jquery/jquery.js' ));`

Comment: unfortunately that did not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to change

`$jq = file_get_contents(includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ));`

to

`$jq = file_get_contents(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/js/jquery/jquery.js');`

and it worked. I'd be interested to know why this works, and the old one doesn't.

Comment: One is using http and one is using the filesystem, is the file accessible through http?

Comment: i believe so, the file permissions on that file was 775. @devon

Comment: There could be lots of other things that affect http access like an .htaccess rule.  I'd assume your includes_url should work, but for something on the same server it's better to use the filesystem instead of the web server to read the file anyways.

Comment: its odd because when i do link in js files from the wp-content folder into `file_get_contents()` it still works. seems like it is an issue with wp-includes?